# ui-route not working when using href attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use ui-route do control my app states but I want the states to be URL oriented.

I want to click on a link and automagically goes to the state with the associated URL.

I followed the In-Depth Guide and my code looks like this (please see plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/wk1RphKq6G3t4GqfppYm):

JS:

```
angularModule.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/management");

        $stateProvider
          .state('management', {
            url: '/',
            template: '<p>:)</p>'
          })
          .state('management.users', {
            url: '/users',
            templateUrl: './users.html'
          });
      }]);
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="PageController">
            <aside class="sidebar col-md-3">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Management</a></li>
                        <li><a href="management/users">Users</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </aside>
            <section class="content col-md-9" ui-view>
            </section>
        </div>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the states, set the root state url to '/':

```
$stateProvider
  .state('management', {
    url: '/',       // INSTEAD OF "index.html"
    template: '<p>:)</p>'
  })
  .state('management.users', {
    url: '/users',
    templateUrl: 'users.html'
  });
```

Next. You're trying to inject `'dev.api'` into the root module:

```
angularModule = angular.module('app', [
  'ui.router',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'dev.api' // HERE
]);
```

**BUT** you never creating the module. You need to change the `service.js` to this:

```
angular
    .module('dev.api', []); // THIS IS HOW YOU DEFINE A NEW MODULE (Without external dependencies)
angular
    .module('dev.api').service('usersApiService', ['$http', function ($http) { .....
```

Now you'll see that the `ui-sref` are working (https://plnkr.co/edit/XbDx2EonQvZYXsyvWhUW?p=preview). Note that you still have some JS errors, but those are related to the logic of your app, and not relevant the the question.

Comment: Still doesn't work when click `ui-sref=".users"`. It should display `users.html`. My plnkr was outdated, sorry.

Comment: @matheusrufca What - Like this? https://plnkr.co/edit/aDPWzW5AgQhutV4g5xri?p=preview

Comment: @matheusrufca Check this: https://plnkr.co/edit/a7zQGr2mfCwW4MVcvgns?p=preview click on the `Management (ui-sref="management") working fine` link, and then you'll see that I have changed the view of the managment state and added link using `ui-sref=".users"` and it's working there. Reason - The link is evaluated within the `management` state, so ui-router "knows" that it's relevant to the current state. While the other links are evaluated globally so ui-router doesn't know how to interpolate it (So in this case you must always use an absolute state names)

Comment: Sorry, i dont see it working. The users.html is not being displayed. Looks like the state doesnt tansitition from management to management.users https://plnkr.co/edit/lrChjK?p=preview

Comment: @matheusrufca That's because of a missing `<ui-view />` in the parent view (Each child view must have a container for the view to be load). Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/gcMTPcxhJLaG3rhb8obP?p=preview (Note that i've changed the template of the `users` state to an inline one (In order to make things easyer for the demo).  Please aviod adding additional reuirements in the comments - It's off-topic to the original post, you're welcome to ask a new question, post here the link and i'll answer you there. I hope you'll find this example helpful

Comment: Ahhh, that's what I was missing. Thanks. I'll edit your answer to make more relevant as answer.

Answer (score 1):

ui-router has it's own html properties , so instead of

`href="management/users"`

you should use

`ui-sref="management.users"`

the path name you use with ui-sref is the state name not the url path itself.

take a look at this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

hope this helps

Comment: So there is no way to control states using `href`?

Comment: In my plnkr I tried `ui-sref="management.users"` and `users.html`  not showned up

Comment: remove the dot that you passed for templateUrl it should work fine

Comment: and to answer your question about href , ui-sref is just a way to tell to ui router where to look but once this gets compiled , ui router will transform your ui-sref into a plain and simple href